# Twitter Rest API Http Request Fail (Android)

Tags: android, api, http, twitter

I'm trying to get some information of user via Rest API of Twitter, but always get 400 response code (Bad request).

```
TwitterAuthToken authToken = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession().getAuthToken();
OAuthSigning oauthSigning = new OAuthSigning(TwitterCore.getInstance().getAuthConfig(), authToken);

Map<String, String> authHeaders = oauthSigning.getOAuthEchoHeadersForVerifyCredentials();

try {
    URL url = new URL("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json");
    HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : authHeaders.entrySet()) {
        connection.setRequestProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    Log.v(MAIN_LOGIN_ACTIVITY_TAG, String.valueOf(connection.getResponseCode()));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I was looking in https://dev.twitter.com/es/twitter-kit/android/oauth-echo, seems to be all right...
Anyone can help me please ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by another way. From **[Access Twitter's REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/api):** *The TwitterCore Kit provides a TwitterApiClient for making authenticated Twitter API requests.*

And finally:

```
if (Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession() != null) {
    AccountService accountService = TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient().getAccountService();
    accountService.verifyCredentials(false, false, new Callback<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<com.twitter.sdk.android.core.models.User> result) {
            Log.v(MAIN_LOGIN_ACTIVITY_TAG, String.valueOf(result.data.getId()));
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException e) {
            Log.v(MAIN_LOGIN_ACTIVITY_TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Greets.